# composite primary key rails not return the keys that were generated in the bank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the composite primary keys ruby ​​to generate composite primary key. After saving a record on the bench with my model, the registration is successful but the fields that represent the key does not return to my object.

1 - In the model, I identified through self.primary_keys who are my fields that make up the primary key.

```
self.primary_keys = :key :deleted
```

2 - In the query that generates active record, there is the following line of code:

```
INSERT INTO "customers" ( "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "key", "deleted" [[ "name", "gui"], [ "created_at", 10.13.2016 13:41:49 UTC], [ "updated_at", 10.13.2016 13:41:49 UTC]]
```

ie RETURNING are specifying correctly who are my key fields and that these values ​​must be returned to set in my object.

After registration, the property "key" remains nil and the "deleted" is false (because of the default value: false). The key is the serial type, so when I saved in the bank it generates the key there, what is missing is the active popular record these values ​​in my object.

Comment: bank? bench? do you mean database? i really do not understand what your question is here. could you give more code examples or something?

Comment: after saving the bank, the query returns the ID that was generated. That's how it should be right